# My output under main is not what I am expecting

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

My assignment is to write a program that asks a user how many integers he/she would like to enter.Dynamically create the array and accept the numbers from the user and place them into
the array. Pass the array to a function to determine the smallest number entered. Print the
smallest number. Use pointer notation wherever appropriate or possible.

I feel like I grasp the passing of the arrays and the pointer notation (please feel free to correct me as I am always eager to learn) but the output under main function is not what I am expecting, or maybe it is what I should be expecting and am not realizing it. here is what I have so far but I am stuck on getting it to output the smallest value in the user inputted array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void CreateValues (int [], int);
int FindSmallest(int [], int);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int numValues = 0;


cout << "How many values would you like to enter?" << endl;
cin >> numValues;

int *pArray = new int[numValues];

CreateValues (pArray, numValues);

FindSmallest(pArray, numValues);

delete[] pArray;

int i = 0;
i = FindSmallest(pArray, sizeof(pArray)/sizeof(pArray[0]));
cout<<"The smallest number in the array is "<<(*pArray + i)<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void CreateValues (int pArray[], int numValues)
{
for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter value #" << i+1<< endl;
    cin >> *(pArray+i);
}
}

int FindSmallest(int pArray[], int numValues)
{

int index = 0;
int x = sizeof(pArray);
for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
{
    if (pArray[i] < pArray[index])
    {

            index = i;
    }

}
return index;
}
```

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

Comment: Obvious thing is you call `FindSmallest()` without saving the result, then delete the array and then call `FindSmallest()` again (on the now deleted array). You probably should stick to arrays and not try to do pointer arithmetic...

Comment: What's your input and output?  What did you expect?

Comment: `sizeof(pArray)/sizeof(pArray[0])` is wrong too... you can't apply that to a pointer (as the first `sizeof` returns you the pointer's size, not the size of pointed-to data, and there's no fix for using `sizeof` as the size is only set at run-time).  Keep using `numValues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
FindSmallest(pArray, numValues);

delete[] pArray;

int i = 0;
i = FindSmallest(pArray, sizeof(pArray)/sizeof(pArray[0]));
```

should be this:

```
int i = 0;
i = FindSmallest(pArray, numValues);
delete [] pArray;
```

or, shortened a bit more:

```
int i = FindSmallest(pArray, numValues);
delete [] pArray;
```

I hope you can see why you have to find the smallest value *before* you delete the array.

Also, `sizeof(pArray)/sizeof(pArray[0])` is a trick that only works for statically-allocated arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First off, why would you `delete[] pArray` when you're using `pArray` later in

```
i = FindSmallest(pArray, sizeof(pArray)/sizeof(pArray[0]));
```

Secondly, your previous `FindSmallest(pArray, numValues);` already does the work of finding minimum value, so the mentioned `i = FindSmallest(...)` is duplicate/abundant. Furthermore, you should declare an `int` to catch the return value of `FindSmallest()`.

```
int min = FindSmallest(pArray, numValues);
cout << "The smallest value is: " << pArray[min];
delete[] pArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

please using this code:

```
int i = 0;
i = FindSmallest(pArray, numValues);
cout<<"The smallest number in the array is "<<*(pArray + i)<<endl;
```

`sizeof(pArray)/sizeof(pArray[0])` is  wrong, because `pArray` is a pointer, so you cann't the element number.